# In my e-commerce site single product page didn't be loaded

Tags: php, laravel, woocommerce

I am developing an e-commerce website in Laravel. On my product page, I have all my products. If I select one product that needs to direct for another page as a single product details page and that page should be loaded. In my case, when I select a product, I am directed to a single product page as well as that product's product id showed in the URL, but the page data didn't be loaded. what could be the problem?

This is my first project in laravel. If anyone can give a hand to sort it out it will be a great help.

SingleProductController.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Product;
use App\Category;

class SingleProductController extends Controller
{
    public function index(Product $product)
    {
        $arr['product'] = $product;
        return view('singleproducts')->with($arr);

    }
    // public function update(Request $request, Product $product)
    // {
    //     $product-> prod_name = $request-> prod_name;
    //     $product-> prod_image_path  = $request-> prod_image_path;
       
    //     return view('singleproducts',['product'=>$product]);
        
    // }
    public function show($id)
    {
       $product = Product::find($id);
       return view ('singleproducts',['product'=>$product]);
    }
}
```

singleproducts.blade.php

```
 <form  action="{{ route('singleproducts',$product->id) }}" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                <div class="mb-xl-14 mb-6">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-5 mb-4 mb-md-0">
                            <div id="sliderSyncingThumb" class="js-slick-carousel u-slick u-slick--slider-syncing u-slick--slider-syncing-size u-slick--gutters-1 u-slick--transform-off"
                                data-infinite="true"
                                data-slides-show="5"
                                data-is-thumbs="true"
                                data-nav-for="#sliderSyncingNav">
                              
                               <div class="js-slide">
                                <img class="img-fluid" src="{{asset('/storage/admin/'.$product ['prod_image_path'] ) }}" alt="Image Description">
                            </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-7 mb-md-6 mb-lg-0">
                            <div class="mb-2">
                                <div class="border-bottom mb-3 pb-md-1 pb-3">
                                    <a href="#" class="font-size-12 text-gray-5 mb-2 d-inline-block"></a>
                                    <h2 class="font-size-25 text-lh-1dot2">{{ $product ['prod_name'] }}</h2>
                                    <div class="mb-2">
                                        <a class="d-inline-flex align-items-center small font-size-15 text-lh-1" href="#">
                                            <div class="text-warning mr-2">
                                                <small class="fas fa-star"></small>
                                                <small class="fas fa-star"></small>
                                                <small class="fas fa-star"></small>
                                                <small class="fas fa-star"></small>
                                                <small class="far fa-star text-muted"></small>
                                            </div>
                                        </a>
                                    </div>
                                 </div>
                              </div>
                           </div>
                      </form>
```

This is my route

```
Route::get('/singleproducts', 'SingleProductController@index')->name('singleproducts');
```

What could be the problem?

Comment: did you try `return view ('singleproducts')->with(['product'=>$product]);` ?

Comment: yes, that is also not supporting.

Comment: Is my controller correct?   Do I need to use an update function or show function?

Comment: check in your blade file -{{$product}}

Comment: check it, not working

Comment: if you call yoour index route, you will passs $arr to the view and no a single product, maybe you need to loop over the array

Comment: please update your code.

Comment: call this route Route::get('/singleproducts/{id}', 'SingleProductController@show')->name('singleproducts');

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you have set your routes well, it may be due to a problem in your blade file. Just try it with a simple blade file and if it works you can search for a problem in your blade file.